# Inequality from proof of theorem on stochastic processes . Theorem from book by Skorokhod Theory of stochastic processes

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes

[image]
Page from book

Need help to prove inequality in red frame. Looks like it should be used inequality involving supremums above , but  I don't see how.

Comment: Just using: if $A_1+A_2+\dots+A_n>B_1+B_2+\dots+B_n+\delta$, $\delta>0$, then at least one of $A_i>B_i$ is true.

Comment: In this case shouldn't (1-a) be in the numerator?

Comment: I.e. $1/(1-a) + a/(1-a)+a^2/(1-a)+... $ tends to $1/(1-a)^2$ not to 1

Comment: good point!  Does the argument work with $(1-a)$ in the numerator?

Comment: Looks like yes, just in last expression in (9) $(1-a)^4$ goes to denominator , but it is  just constant multiplier.

Comment: We might need to change the $a<1$ and $2a^4>1$ to something else.